# DevExpress DataGrid

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to populate a DevExpress DataGrid with selected attributes of all the files contained in a filepath 
This is what I currently have ("Name." is a placeholder)

```
private void grList_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
    {

        DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        switch (e.Column.FieldName)
        {
            case "Name":
                e.Value = source.GetFiles(Name.ToString());
            break;
            case "FullName":
                e.Value = source.GetFiles(Name.ToString());
                break;
            case "Extention":
                e.Value = source.GetFiles(Name.ToString());
                break;
            case "LastAccessTime":
                e.Value = source.GetFiles(Name.ToString());
                break;
            case "LastWriteTime":
                e.Value = source.GetFiles(Name.ToString());
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Is your problem you're unsure how to render things in a DataGrid? or that you don't know how to access the properties of a file?
If the former, consult the documentation for DevExpress DataGrid. If the latter, I refer you to the MSDN documentation for FileInfo https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

General advice: Do not ask questions that are so broad, and *always* explain what first you have tried, and what didn't work.

Comment: @Squiggle Thanks. My problem is currently both. The event should handle the data population into the DataGrid, but the biggest portion of this issue is reading the Name, FullName, Extention, LastAccessTime and LastWriteTime out of `DirectoryInfo`. I used `dataGridView1.DataSource = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles()` on a standard DataGridView and it returns all possible attributes, unfortunately, for this solution, I need to use the DevExpress tools

Comment: Please reduce this question to address just a single problem. And importantly, check StackOverflow for existing solutions to each of these. In your question please supply more information about what you have already attempted.

Answer (score 0):

The CustomUnboundColumData is fired for each cell that is visible and of unbound type. This means if you have 5 unbound columns and 100 files, your calls will be made 500 times each time the grid is redrawn.

Why not using a datasource approach? For example, you could populate it with code like following

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");
var files = d.GetFiles("*.*").Select(x =>  new
    {
        x.Name,
        x.FullName,
        x.Extension,
        x.LastAccessTime,
        x.LastWriteTime
    }).ToList();
gridControl.DataSource = files;
```

I used a dynamic data, you can also use a class. All you need to do in your grid is to set the Columns to the corresponding fieldname and make them bound.